# What is Mobile Device Management and How can I use for my enterprise?

Tags: applications

What is Mobile Device Management and How can I use for my enterprise?

What is the benefits of using MDM?

Answer (score 1):

All MDM products are built with an idea of Containerization. The MDM Container is secured using latest crypto techniques (AES-256 or more preferred). All the corporate data like email, documents, enterprise application are encrypted and processed inside the container. This ensures that corporate data is separated from user’s personal data on the device. Additionally, encryption for entire device and/or SD Card can also be enforced depending on MDM product capability.

**Secure email**: MDM products allow organization to integrate their existing email setup to be easily integrated with MDM environment. Almost all MDM products support easy integration with Exchange Server (2003/2007/2010), Office365, Lotus Notes, BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES) and others. This provided flexibility of configuring Email-over-air. Secure Docs: It is frequently seen that, employees copy attachments downloaded from corporate email to their personal devices and then misuse it. MDM can easily restrict/disable clipboard usage in/out of Secure Container; forwarding attachments to external domains can be restricted, downloading/saving attachments on SD Card. This ensures corporate data is not left insecure.

**Secure browser**: Using secure browser can avoid many potential security risks. Every MDM solution comes with built-in custom browser. Administrator can disable native browsers to force user to use Secure Browser, which is also inside the MDM container. URL filtering can be enforced to add additional productivity measure.

**Secure app catalog**: Organization can distribute, manage, and upgrade applications on employee’s device using App Catalogue. It allows applications to be pushed on user device directly from the App Store or push an enterprise developed private application through the App Catalogue. This provides an option for the organization to deploy devices in Kiosk Mode or Lock-Down Mode.

**Additional MDM features**

There are plenty of other features depending on which MDM product is chosen:

- Policy Enforcing: There are multiple types of policies which can be enforced on MDM users.

  - Personal Policy: According to corporate environment, highly customizable
  - Device Platform specific: policies for advanced management of Android, IOS, Windows and Blackberry devices.
  - Compliance Policies/Rules
- VPN configuration
- Application Catalogue
- Pre-defined Wi-Fi and Hotspot settings
- Jailbreak/Root detection
- Remote Wipe of corporate data
- Remote Wipe of entire device
- Device remote locking
- Remote messaging/buzz
- Disabling native apps on device

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management)

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Device Management (MDM)](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-device-management-software/) is a term that is used to define managing mobile devices such as mobile phones, tablet and laptop computers remotely. MDM is available on-premise or as [cloud instance](https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/cloud-based-mdm/).

MDM helps your Enterprise to manage devices of employees remotely by administrator and provide security to the Enterprise data in the devices. MDM have the following features:

1. Security: MDM provides security by encrypting Enterprise-related files on the device. If the device appears to be stolen or missing, then the device can either be locked down or wiped out to protect data. Full-wipe wipes the entire device and selective wipe wipes Enterprise-specific data from the device.

Security can also be achieved through several in-built security policies in MDM. These policies can be ranged from setting the password complexity to restricting WiFi, Bluetooth and mobile data.

2. An ideal MDM will support multiple platforms, such as iOS, Android, Windows Phone and Mobile, Windows PC, MacOS, WatchOS, Blackberry etc.
3. Scalability: An MDM should be able to handle any number of devices at a time.

Other features include

- Mobile Application Management: Includes features like deploying apps remotely and whitelisting or blacklisting apps.
- Mobile Content Management: Allows an Enterprise to send documents to employees while encrypting document, password protecting the document, and requiring authentication to access the document.
- Mobile Expense Management: Helps an Enterprise to calculate network usage in the Enterprise as well as below every department and employees.
- Kiosk mode: Disables all buttons and user interface except that of an app or a webpage (set via MDM console) thus helps securely use the device as Kiosk.
- Mobile Email Management.