# Copy an entire Android Image to multiple devices

Tags: 7.1-nougat

First and foremost, let me tell you that I am everything but a professional when it comes to the Android OS. I've just been using it casually up to now, but I do have a rather annoying task at hand right now.

The issueI have is Setting up About 150 Android devices, disabling the Google apps, changing some Settings and installing one app. Obviously that task would take about for ever if I did everything by hand, so my thought was to just set up one and then copy all the properties and stuff to the other ones. Unfortunately I have no idea if that even is possible.

Rooting the devices is not an Option as the warranty should stay intact. The devices are Zebra TC200J with Android 7.1.2

I'd really appreciate any help about the process or any other ways on how to ease the process.

Comment: Since you can't root those devices MDM is one option [What is Mobile Device Management and How can I use for my enterprise?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/155616)

Comment: That's what I was afraid, but MDM does seem like a good alternative. Do you have any tips on a specific MDM provider that would enable the stuff I have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, never used it

Comment: Is (temporarily) unlocking the bootloader an option?

Answer (score 0):

MDM(Mobile Device Management) is a great option when managing multiple devices. Google has their own [MDM](https://gsuite.google.co.in/intl/en_in/products/admin/mobile/).

> MDM begins at a centralized location, usually a single workstation or
>   computer. From this centralized point, the administrator can use the
>   Mobile Device Management software to oversee all the devices in the
>   network. This is done by using the software to set up a suite of
>   policies so that all devices that have access to the network will
>   adhere to enterprise standards.
>
> Once the policies are set, administrators can then enroll smartphones,
>   tablets, laptops, and even desktop computers into the network.
>   Depending upon software capabilities and corporate security
>   requirements, device enrollment can be accomplished, either by
>   physically connecting devices to the workstation, or wirelessly.
>
> From this point, enrolled devices can be configured to meet enterprise
>   needs through a host of options including personalized app catalogs,
>   user restrictions, app blacklisting, and so forth. These
>   configurations help to ensure that all devices comply to set policies
>   while at the same time allowing users the best device experience
>   possible. At any time a device is enrolled into the network, MDM
>   software allows administrators to make policy changes, push apps,
>   install updates, and any other changes that are necessary.
>   Administrators can even disenroll and restrict devices whenever
>   necessary.

There is an alternative, you could enable developer options and enable USB debugging. Later a simple script that runs `adb tcpip 5555` for all devices allowing you to connect them to a network. Now you can perform actions on all phones including keystrokes using `keyevent` by relaying the devices. Something like `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE`.

I would prefer MDM as it is a little hassle-free, but using adb has worked for me